# Blender Render won't render smoke

Tags: smoke-simulation

I am new to blender and I am trying to make smoke. But my smoke won't render in Blender Render but it will render in openGL.

My Render Settings

[image]

My Domain

[image]

My Flow

[image]

Comment: SimonCircle Post a ScreenShot of what you see in viewport & render.

Comment: Please remember that we don't know anything about your project. Be as descriptive as possible to describe your issue and inlude relevant screenshots to illustrate your post.

Comment: Sorry, I updated it with screenshots